# Calculate distance to the closest neighbour between two sets of points on a grid

Tags: geometry

Assume I have two sets of points homogeneously spread across space. I want to calculate the average distance to the closest neighbor between the points in each set.

For example, as detailed in the data below, I have a specific number of cabinets and distribution points in a broadband network at each exchange.

```
exchange_id total_premises  area_km2    cabinets    distribution_points
     1           20000         10          40                336
     2           15000         8           30                252
     3           9000          4           18                151
     4           8000          3           16                134
```

If the cabinets and distribution points were assumed to be arranged in a grid pattern, how could I calculate the average distance to the closest neighbor for fiber optic rollout?

Edit: Changed to focus on average distance to the closest neighbor

Comment: I am afraid that what you are looking for is not the right parameter. Having worked on a somewhat related subject, a better parameter is to look for the average of the random variable "distance to the closest neighbour". Otherwise, points that are distant one from the other will soon be dominant in your average, without any profit.

Comment: Thanks for the advice JeanMarie - I will edit the question appropriately